# TOOL like Microsoft visual studio for generating CSS file from HTML file

Tags: css

I like to know is there is any tool by which i can generate CSS file from HTML file, tool should have property change feature like Microsoft visual studio have,like i have img tag in my HTML file so tool have a window from which I can set any style property of that tag and tool generate corresponding CSS of it

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a WYSIWYG html editor that allows you to edit the css rules for elements in your visual design?

Adobe [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/) is probably the most popular (although not necessarily best) non-Microsoft WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a web and desktop development suite called [Microsoft Expression](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/) which may fit your needs if you're already using with Visual Studio.

Check out [Microsoft Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx).